# Error while forwarding to another html page using doGET in Jetty 9

Tags: javascript, servlets, get, server, jetty

On Jetty 9, I'm trying to send some data to the server using **Javascript**:

```
var logInBtn = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "LogIn", press:function(){

        // Retrieve the information from the text fields
        var oParameters = {
              "userIDInput" : sap.ui.getCore().getElementById('userIDInput').getValue(),
              "passwordInput" : sap.ui.getCore().getElementById('passwordInput').getValue()
        };

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        //console.log(oParameters);
        // Post data to the server
        oModel.loadData("10.161.34.8:8080", oParameters, true, 'GET');
        } 
    });
```

Then I want to forward the current page based on that data.  I can receive the data but I am not able to forward the page at all.
This is my **doGet** method in the **servlet**:

```
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//***I have tried the relative address as well***
         request.getRequestDispatcher("http://10.161.34.8:8080/UserAccount.html").forward(request, response);
    }
```

This are my **handlers**:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletHandler ServHandler = new ServletHandler();
    ServHandler.addServletWithMapping(Servlet.class, "/*");

    FilterHolder cors = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
    cors.setName("cross-origin");
    FilterMapping fm = new FilterMapping();
    fm.setFilterName("cross-origin");
    fm.setPathSpec("*");
    ServHandler.addFilter(cors, fm );

    ResourceHandler resource_handler1 = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler1.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler1.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html"});//webpage to show up
    resource_handler1.setResourceBase("../../Documents/GitHub/ProjectASB/WebContent/");//The address of the content(. must be there)
    ContextHandler contextHandler1= new ContextHandler("/");
    contextHandler1.setHandler(resource_handler1);

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandler1, ServHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

But I get this **error**:

```
2016-06-09 13:48:51.629:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.1.v20140108
2016-06-09 13:48:51.640:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@6e06451e{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-06-09 13:48:51.714:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@710726a3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-06-09 13:48:59.919:WARN:oejur.FileResource:qtp400136488-28: bad alias for C:\Users\i853260\Documents\GitHub\ProjectASB\WebContent\10.161.34.8:8080: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (path C:\Users\i853260\Documents\GitHub\ProjectASB\WebContent\10.161.34.8:8080, working dir C:\Users\i853260\hdbstudio_rev\NoiseServer)
2016-06-09 13:48:59.926:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp400136488-28: /10.161.34.8:8080
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) of a null object returned from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)
    at servletPackage.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-) takes a path.

A path that is relative to the current servlet, not a full URL.

You might also want to test for null on the return of `getRequestDispatcher(String)` before attempting to use `.forward()` on it

**// Update**

Since you are using `getRequestDispatcher()` you *have to use* a `ServletContextHandler` (or better, such as a `WebAppContext`), because the `getRequestDispatcher()` requires a valid `ServletContext` to function.

Using the raw `ServletHandler` is not a good choice for you (your needs have outgrown that class)

> `ServletHandler` is really more of an internal class to `ServletContextHandler` anyway, used to bind the `ServletContext` to the list of Servlets, along with the call chain for any Filters you have.

Notes:

- Don't mix `ResourceHandler` and `ServletContextHandler`, they do the same thing, but will fight each other.
- The `baseResource` in the `ServletContextHandler` defines the `ServletContext` base resource, and is used by the `DefaultServlet` to serve static files, as well as being used for context specific configuration / resource lookups
- Use the `DefaultServlet`, its light years better then the primitive `ResourceHandler` and far more configurable.
- Don't map servlets to `/*`, otherwise you'll be in charge of serving all of the content from the server, not allowing Jetty to serve the static content via the `ServletContextHandler` behavior.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    File webroot = new File("Documents/Project/WebContent");
    if (!webroot.exists())
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find webroot: " + webroot);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webroot));
    context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"index.html"});

    context.addServlet(DummyServlet.class, "/dummy/");

    FilterHolder cors = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD");
    cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM,
        "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
    context.addFilter(cors, "/dummy/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    // Lastly, the default servlet for root content
    // It is important that this is last.
    ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
    holderPwd.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    context.addServlet(holderPwd, "/");

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.addHandler(context);
    handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I have tried verities of relative addresses, none of the work. Do I need to add something on the javascript side?

Comment: Oh, i see you are not using the `ServletContextHandler`, but you are using the internal `ServletHandler` class directly (not the best choice).  Let me see if I can rework your example ...